# cscript from works on w7, not on 2008r2

Tags: c#, wsh

I have a vbs script that usually I run manually.
Double click and it works perfectly.

I decided to make it work automatically, called by a c# process (a service):

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\script.vbs";
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Testing on my local machine it works with no problem, moving that in a W2008 R2 server it not working anymore.

I feel that is something related to the user privilege, but I'm administrator in both machines.

Can you help me figure out the issue?

Thanks

Comment: `in a W2008 R2 server it not working anymore.` Could you be more specific on **what** is not working? Does it not start the script? Is the script even there at `C:\script.vbs`? Does it throw an exception? Tell us more.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I'd like to be more precise, but I cannot. This script should run excel macro. If I run the same command via cmd (in both machines), the output is there. If I run the code I showed before nothing happened. No error, no exception. Simply no file in the expected folder

Comment: Then check atleast if you get in the entry point of the script when invoking the script via C# with a `Process` (create a dummy file or something) and go on from there. Does the script fail or does invoking the script fail? Maybe there are version differences? The C:\ drive is different? `cscript.exe` is not where you expected it?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt The files are there: if I run (in cmd) 'C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe C:\script.vbs', it is working.
If I run the same with the code above the script is not working.
The code is the same (c# and vbs) in both machines and the path is correct (as I said the cmd command is working properly).
Moreover, the c# code running in w7 machine works properly

Comment: Use `On Error Goto 0` and comment up all `On Error Resume Next` (add `'` apostrophe prefix) in your `script.vbs`. Then, `Cscript` should show error(s)... _This script should run excel macro_ - is `excel` installed there on W2008 R2 server?

Comment: @JosefZ: 'is excel installed there on W2008 R2 server?' guys, the script is working fine if called via cmd. Is not working if called via c# code. Obviously Excel is installed. 
Moreover, I "echo" at the beginning of the script. I think the script is not even executed

Comment: Any suggestion at least on how to isolate the issue?